# How should I access generated children of a custom HTML component in an idiomatic React way?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I am attempting to create a search bar using a custom HTML component for predictive text input. The way this component is built, it generates several plain HTML children that I need to act on to get full features. Specifically, I need to execute a blur action on one of the generated  elements when the user presses escape or enter.

I got it to work using a ref on the custom component and calling getElementsByClassName on the ref, but using getElementsByClassName does not seem like the best solution. It pierces through the virtual and has odd side effects when testing.

This is a snippet of the component being rendered:

```html
<predictive-input id='header-search-bar-input' type='search'
  value={this.state.keywords}
  ref={(ref: any) => this.predictiveInput = ref}
  onKeyDown={(e: React.KeyboardEvent<any>) => this.handleKeyDown(e)}>
</predictive-input>
```

and the keyDown handler:

```js
private handleKeyDown(e: React.KeyboardEvent<any>) {
    // must access the underlying input element of the kat-predictive-input
    let input: HTMLElement = this.predictiveInput.getElementsByClassName('header-row-text value')[0] as HTMLElement;
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        // blur the predictive input when the user presses escape
        input.blur();
    } else if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        // commit the search when user presses enter
        input.blur();
        // handles action of making actual search, using search bar contents
        this.commitSearch();
    }
}
```

The  element renders two  children, one for the bar itself and one for the predictive dropdown. The classes of the underlying  in the first  are 'header-row-text' and 'value', so the element is correctly selected, but I am worried that this is violating proper React style.

I am using React 16.2, so only callback refs are available. I would rather avoid upgrading, but if a 16.3+ solution is compelling enough, I could consider it.

Comment: do you have any control over the innards of `predictive-input`?

Comment: It is a component made by another team at my company for internal consumption. In a certain sense I have control, in that I could make requests and I know it will not be changed drastically without being notified, but I can't directly access it within the React virtual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any control over the input then this is the best approach in my opinion.

It's not ideal, but as you're stuck with a 3rd party component you can only choose from the methods that are available to you. In this case, your only real options are to find the element based on its class, or its position in the hierarchy. Both might change if the package is updated, but if I had to choose which would be more stable, I'd go for `className`.